# With out TypeCasting , how to convert float value to an integer

Tags: java

How to convert float value to  an integer value using wrapper classes with out typecasting.

Comment: Why don't you play a bit with the API?

Comment: Please read [ask] a good question ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is autoboxing? 
You can simply use `Float.intValue()` you will get Integer.
`Integer yourI = yourF.intValue();`

Comment: Hey, input is like: int num=50;   float ft=132.45; Then , you should not use Integer in= new Integer(num) and so as this is also a typecast

Comment: Maybe try num = Math.round(ft);?
Not sure what you really want, if num is already initialized.

Comment: Actually Math.round(ft) will return the rounded value , But I need the actual value that is not rounded (for Ex: 16.3 as 16 and 16.9 as 16, here round off doesn't occur)

Comment: Well, now I am confused. In your question You wrote, that you want to use wrapper class. Then in your comment you say you do not want to use them.
int i = (int) f; This example uses typecasting. the one I wrote as answer uses wrappers.
If you need actual value, search for 'floor'.

Comment: Actually there is a way without out typecasting and with using Wrapper class